# why var of beta is not included in var of y in linear regression

Tags: regression, variance

I know as a known fact that in linear regression

y= X*beta +error, so var(y|X) = var(X*beta+error|X) = sigma^2, where sigma is the std. dev of errors.

But in regression we also have mean and variance of beta estimate?

counfused how they all played together. How come we consider beta to be fixed when getting variance of y?

Comment: $\beta$ is fixed but its estimate is not

Comment: then how come X is RV (not fixed) but beta is fixed? and is error fixed?

Comment: one can define a prior on $\beta$ and make it a RV, but typically it's assumed to be fixed. On the other hand, its estimate depends on data, so it's not fixed. Error, by its nature, is not fixed.